# Python Flask, connect another url

Tags: python, url, flask, flask-restful

I simplify my requirement to this simple code

```
from flask import Flask, request
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def root():
    payload = {'Message': 'yo','Port':'123'}
    r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/test", data=payload)
    return r.text


@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    return request.form['Message']+','+request.form['Port']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I've tested the url '127.0.0.1:5000/test' by google's Postman.
I send the data to the url, and It worked, can return the result I wanted.

And I created another .py to test the url, too. It also can show the result I wanted.

```
import requests

payload = {'Message':'yo','Port':'123'}
r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/test", data=payload)
print r.text
```

Then I put the same code below

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def root():
```

I want to use the url '127.0.0.1:5000/' to send data to the '127.0.0.1:5000/test' (I also Use google's Postman)
And it can't worked... it always show 'loading...'

Is there a better way to implement my requirement ?
I will thank you so so so much ~!!

Comment: Add `threaded=True` to `app.run()`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of sending a local `POST` request, which would take a lot longer time, just have them both route to the same function, and set defaults.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test():
    return request.form.get('Message', 'yo') + ',' + request.form.get('Port', '123')
```

Which would respond normally to all POST requests on `/test`, and with a GET to `/`, it works the same as POSTing `{'Message': 'yo', 'Port': '123'}` to `/test`